# tinyMCE custom button popup tabs and colorbox

Tags: jquery, tinymce

as the title already says I need to setup a custom menubutton in tinyMCE 4.

Setting up the button is no problem but how can I implement multiple tabs in the popup and an colorbox?

I tried the "colorpicker"-type and that worked but a colorbox like in the table plugin is way much better...

can anyone help?

Comment: ok, I managed to get the tabs working... just added the bodyTape:"tabpanel" option in the windowManager.open function

Answer (score 0):

ok, I managed to get the tabs working... just added the bodyTape:"tabpanel" option in the windowManager.open function

for everyone having the same problem:

```
editor.addButton('testbtn', {
                text: 'Box einfügen',
                icon: false,
                onclick : function() {
                    editor.windowManager.open({
                        title: 'Edit Box',
                        bodyType: "tabpanel",
                         body: [{
                            title: "General",
                            type: "form"
                        }, {
                            title: "Embed",
                            type: "container",
                            layout: "flex",
                            direction: "column",
                            align: "stretch",
                            padding: 10,
                            spacing: 10
                        }],
                    });
                }
            });
```